# Mounting secrets directly to /run/secrets in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I do have an existing application that used docker and docker compose so far. I want to operate this app in a Kubernetes cluster. Shouldn't be a big deal, right? But so far I failed because of the used secrets.

The application expects a secret to be present in a file at: `/run/secrets/webhook_secret`, where `webhook_secret` is the file containing the secret.

I created a secret with kubectl like this:

```
   kubectl create secret                                                       
      generic webhook-secret \
      --from-literal=webhook_secret=123 \
      --namespace my-app
```

I tried to mount the secret in the manifest with...

```
  ...
  volumeMounts:
  - name: secrets
    mountPath: "/run/secrets"
    readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: secrets
    secret:
      secretName: webhook-secret
  ...
```

But then the pod is not able to start, as Kubernetes also tries to mount the same directory and so issues with run/secrets/kubernetes.io occur...

`Warning  Failed     3m1s (x4 over 3m37s)   kubelet            Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/e79f634a-2abe-4c47-ae50-c4beb5b66ae6/volumes/kubernetes.io~projected/kube-api-access-grl42" to rootfs at "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount": mkdir /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/my-app-container/rootfs/run/secrets/kubernetes.io: read-only file system: unknown`

Any idea how I can provide the secret as required by the application?

Regards and thanks,
Thomas

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to write a file on a read only folder which might not exists: `/secret` is not present in standard linux os.
Try to set your volumeMount parameter to `readOnly: false`.
I think there is another misconfiguration. You want to have the file `/run/secrets/webhook_secret`. The way you did it, you will have the file `/run/secrets/webhook_secret/webhook_secret`. Just set the mount path to `/run/secrets`.

Comment: I edited my question, as it was maybe a bit misleading. I tried the mountPath: "/run/secrets", but as Kubernetes is using that also for the run/secrets/kubernetes.io stuff it somehow clashes. Setting it to readOnly also did not work

Comment: You cannot mount the secret at `/run/secrets` because this directory is reserved for Kubernetes to mount its own secrets. You won't be able to mount your secret into that directory, so it's best to change your application where it expects that secret of yours.

Comment: I was afraid of that  Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be perfectly possible to mount your own secrets into the `/var/run/secrets` or `/run/secrets` path. Even in the scenario where Kuberbetes is concurrently using that path for system-related tasks. This commonly happens when, for instance,  you are running a cluster with 2+ nodes and Kubernetes starts projecting it's system objects like secrets, tokens, certifates, etc. into `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`.

I don't know the exact specifics of your case, but you might want to look into `subPath`. When your application expects secrets to be available in `/run/secrets`, you can do so something like:

```
...
containers:
    - name: myContainer
      image: "someImage:1.0.0"
volumeMounts:
  - name: mySecretVolumeName
    mountPath: "/run/secrets/webhook_secret"
    readOnly: true
    subPath: webhook-secret
volumes:
  - name: mySecretVolumeName
    secret:
      secretName: secrets
      items:
        - key: webhook-secret
          path: webhook-secret
...
```

People started bumping into the issue you're experiencing (if I understand you correctly) a few years ago: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65835

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: I had to remove the items parts in your example, but then it worked. I am able to mount a secret to run/secrets/webhook_secret directly. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great! I now see that `secretName:` in your post is `webhook-secret`. Therefore, in my post the path in `items:` should be `webhook-secret` (instead of `webhook_secret`). My bad! (edited post for future readers)